# When will TensorFlow Federated be ready for production?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

Currently trying to use federated analytics (and eventually federated learning) at work. We are exploring PyTorch Federated and TensorFlow Federated. When I watched the TensorFlow Federated Tutorials on Google TechTalk, all tutorials were being connected to simulated data sets available locally and they confirmed that TensorFlow Federated is only ready for simulations and not for production. Do we know when TensorFlow Federated will be ready for production?

Answer (score 0):

TFF is still only for research and simulations for now.

Comment: Could you provide any links/resources on this?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/federated  "TFF has been developed to facilitate open research and experimentation with Federated Learning (FL)"